# При изменении масштаба сайта кнопка в меню перекрывает текст в меню

Tags: html, css

На [этом сайте](http://corporate-ok.ru/) при уменьшении масштаба кнопка "Заказать звонок" в верхнем фиксированном меню начинает перекрывать пункты навигации. Можно ли как-то решить эту проблему? Или эта проблема браузеров?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можете воспользоваться этим скриптом:

```
function hscrollbar() {
var left = 
    window.pageXOffset ? window.pageXOffset : 
    document.documentElement.scrollLeft ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft : 
    document.body.scrollLeft;

    //Здесь, ID Вашего fixed блока
    document.getElementById('header').style.left = -left+"px";
}
window.onscroll = hscrollbar;
window.onresize = hscrollbar;
```

Живой пример:
http://jsfiddle.net/HA3IK/FxXy9/1/

Comment: Не совсем понял, как скрипт работает, но наверное margin уменьшается? Дело в том, что у меня нет никаких отступов слева и справа от пунктов меню.

Comment: @Виктор Павлов, скрипт задает отрицательное положение стиля ***left***, параллельно/синхронно/одновременно с положением горизонтального скролла (в пикселях). Получается, что блок просто прячется за границу браузера, когда Вы тяните горизонтальный скролл вправо и возвращается обратно, когда тяните влево.

Причем тут отступы слева и справа, от пунктов меню? Вы хотите задать еще и отступы? Потому, что в данном случае, они тут ни при чем.

Если Вы об этом отступе говорите?  
http://puu.sh/64yOI.jpg  
...То Я подчеркнул в консоли (в низу): какой стиль - какому классу - надо задать

Comment: аааа, понял. Спасибо.